# Pull the last record before certain date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have two tables. Table 1 has the the employees and dates they call in sick.

**Table 1:**

| Employee | Date Called |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2020 |
| B | 2/5/2020 |
| A | 8/2/2020 |
| B | 12/20/2020 |

Table 2 has the record where the employees travel to and when.

**Table 2:**

| Employee | Location | Date Arrived |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | New York | 10/1/2019 |
| A | Boston | 12/15/2019 |
| B | Los Angeles | 1/1/2020 |
| A | Miami | 6/6/2020 |
| B | San Diego | 10/6/2020 |

I need to query the the location when the employee calls in sick, so that the table looks like below. I'm having a hard time pulling the last "date arrived" before the call in date. Thanks for the help!

| Employee | Date Called | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1/1/2020 | Boston |
| B | 2/5/2020 | Los Angeles |
| A | 8/2/2020 | Miami |
| B | 12/20/2020 | San Diego |

Comment: To be honest, I tried to picture the logic in my head but couldn't figure out where to start with.

Comment: First, write a query that lists all the arrival dates and locations _prior_ to a sick date. Then post that here. That's half the work. Also please post the specific SQL Server version `SELECT @@VERSION`

Comment: I have to recommend a tutorial rather than SO if you don't know where to start.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Don't leave us guessing at whether the "date" columns are `date` or `nvarchar(max)` of something else, share your DDL.

Comment: @DaleK Any tutorial you would recommend that may answer this question?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Didn't know that was the direction to go, so didn't post any thing not helpful.

Comment: @HABO Thanks for the tips. Now understand what the expectations are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT Employee,
       DateCalled,
       (
           SELECT TOP 1
               Location
           FROM table2
           WHERE DateArrived <= t1.DateCalled
                 AND Employee = t1.Employee
           ORDER BY DateArrived DESC
       ) Location
FROM table1 t1;
```

Or you can use `Left join` like this:

```
SELECT t.Employee,
       t.DateCalled,
       t.Location
FROM
(
    SELECT t1.Employee,
           t1.DateCalled,
           t2.Location,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.Employee,
                                           t1.DateCalled
                              ORDER BY t2.DateArrived DESC
                             ) rw
    FROM table1 t1
        LEFT JOIN table2 t2
            ON t2.Employee = t1.Employee
               AND t2.DateArrived <= t1.DateCalled
) t
WHERE t.rw = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this uses `lead()` and `left join`:

```
select t1.*, t2.location
from table1 t1 left join
     (select t2.*, lead(date_arrived) as next_date_arrived
      from table2 t2
     ) t2
     on t1.employee = t2.employee and
        t1.date_called >= t2.date_arrived and
        (t1.date_called < t2.date_arrived or t2.date_arrived is null);
```

Note that this structure makes it easy to add other columns from `table2` into the result set.